# Can log entries (or log bundles) be signed?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library, system.diagnostics

In order to ensure that nobody is modifying the log, I search for a way to [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the log entries, and perhaps even bundle log entities and sign whole bundles.

Are there a way to do that using either [System.Diagnostics.TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [Enterprise Logging Application Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff664569(v=PandP.50).aspx)? Or another logging framework that allows to customize where the logs are stored?

Comment: You could write out the log entries encrypted. Or you could hash the log at regular points and have a program which verifies the hashes.

Comment: Are there any standard components that can do this? That is, how much custom code is needed for doing that?